# jQuery if excel cell value is negative, color text red

Tags: jquery, excel, xml, datatables

I'm using the Datatables library to render HTML table and on button click output an excel document. Here is the code I currently have:

```
    $(document).ready( function () {
      $('#mainTable').DataTable({
        fixedHeader: false,
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
          {
            extend: 'copy', 
            exportOptions: {
              columns: ':not(:first-child)',
              rows: ':visible'
            }
          },
          {
            extend: 'excelHtml5',
            title: 'Profit and Loss Report', 
            messageTop: `Ran on ${(new Date()).toLocaleString()} for period <xsl:value-of select="P_PERIOD_NUM"/> - FY<xsl:value-of select="P_PERIOD_YEAR"/>`,
            messageBottom: `Companies: <xsl:value-of select="P_COMP_CHILD"/> Cost Centers: <xsl:value-of select="P_CC_CHILD_1"/><xsl:value-of select="P_CC_CHILD_2"/>`,
            // Function iterates over each row and applies styling if conditions are met
            customize: function (xlsx) {
                var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
                var rows = $('row:gt(2)', sheet);
                rows.each(function () {
                  // bold all rows where first cell ends with : (totals, % or revs)
                  if ($('c:first-of-type is t', this).text().endsWith(':')) {$('c', this).attr('s', '2');}
                  // highlight red all rows that start with - (negative numbers)
                  $('c', this).each(function() {
                    if ($('v', this).text().startsWith('-')) {
                        $(this).attr('s', '11');
                    }
                  });
                });
            }
          },
          {
            extend: 'pdfHtml5', 
            title: 'Profit and Loss Report', 
            orientation: 'landscape', 
            pageSize: 'LEGAL',
            messageTop: `Ran on ${(new Date()).toLocaleString()} for period <xsl:value-of select="P_PERIOD_NUM"/> - FY<xsl:value-of select="P_PERIOD_YEAR"/>`,
            messageBottom: `Companies: <xsl:value-of select="P_COMP_CHILD"/> Cost Centers: <xsl:value-of select="P_CC_CHILD_1"/><xsl:value-of select="P_CC_CHILD_2"/>`
          } 
        ],
        "ordering": false,
        paging: false
      });
```

As you can see I have a function that iterates over every row of the excel file. The first if statement looks for ':' at the end of the first cell's string. Summation rows use this character, so they are bolded.

However, the issue I'm having is with this piece of code:

```
if ($('v', this).text().startsWith('-')) {
  $(this).attr('s', '11');
}
```

The if statement works as intended; it selects every cell that starts with - (negative numbers). the if statement's body is where the issue is. I want to use red font to show negative numbers. attribute "s" of value "11" denotes white text and red background. That is as close as I've got. I haven't been able to find anything that actually just sets the text as red.

Edit: I found a list of values for excel's s attribute here in case it is useful: https://datatables.net/reference/button/excelHtml5

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I managed to change the font to the appropriate color. I added my own answer to the question that you can see below. What I had to do was overwrite the default font/fill/borders with my own custom values. Then I could reference these by using the "s" attribute like normal.

Comment: Happy to be proved wrong :) Glad you got it working - although that's some damn ugly code thanks to Excel formatting being an absolute nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: if you only need to have one the red font value, then you can replace one of the preset fonts:**

```
var styles = xlsx.xl['styles.xml'];
// change white font to red for negative numbers
$('fonts font:nth-child(2) color', styles).attr('rgb', 'FFFF0000');
// reference this font with $('c').attr('s', '1');
```

Okay so I actually managed to make this work. You have to use custom font/fill/borders values. These values are available in the "styles.xml" file. Please see below code:

```
            customize: function (xlsx) {
                // add in custom font for negative numbers
                var styles = xlsx.xl['styles.xml']
                $('fonts', styles).empty();
                $('fonts', styles).attr('count', '3');
                $('fonts', styles).append(`
                  <font>
                    <sz val="11"/>
                    <color rgb="00000000"/>
                    <name val="Calibri"/>
                    <family val="2"/>
                    <scheme val="minor"/>
                  </font>
                  <font>
                    <b/>
                    <sz val="11"/>
                    <color rgb="00000000"/>
                    <name val="Calibri"/>
                    <family val="2"/>
                    <scheme val="minor"/>
                  </font>
                  <font>
                    <sz val="11"/>
                    <color rgb="FFFF0000"/>
                    <name val="Calibri"/>
                    <family val="2"/>
                    <scheme val="minor"/>
                  </font>
                `);
                $('fills', styles).empty();
                $('fills', styles).attr('count', '2');
                $('fills', styles).append(`
                <fill>
                  <patternFill patternType="none"/>
                </fill>
                <fill>
                  <patternFill patternType="gray125"/>
                </fill>
                `);
                $('borders', styles).empty();
                $('borders', styles).attr('count', '1');
                $('borders', styles).append(`
                <border>
                  <left/>
                  <right/>
                  <top/>
                  <bottom/>
                  <diagonal/>
                </border>
                `);
                var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
                var rows = $('row:gt(2)', sheet);
                rows.each(function () {
                  // bold all rows where first cell ends with : (totals, % or revs)
                  if ($('c:first-of-type is t', this).text().endsWith(':')) {$('c', this).attr('s', '1');}
                  // highlight red all rows that start with - (negative numbers)
                  $('c', this).each(function() {
                    if ($('v', this).text().startsWith('-')) {
                        console.log($('v', this).text());
                        $(this).attr('s', '2');
                    }
                  });
                });
            }
```

Here I am stripping out the default fonts, fills and borders. I'm adding in three fonts, a standard black font, a bolded black font, and a red font.

I also added in standard fills and borders.

I can then reference these using the "s" attributes. The underlying values are just different.